# Find pattern in file powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this pattern thats composed by a quantity, a description and a price. Please not that the numbers and text can change everytime.

I need to use powershell to find and save the results. So far I got this... the pattern format is what is driving me crazy.

```
$example_line = '3.00 CEBICHE CORVINA PI   26,805.00'
$pattern= '\d.\d\d \D'
$results = $example_line | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches
$results.Matches.Value
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT. After seeing the answers Im trying regex to build the array.

I dont know why its not working for me... Im reading the txt file and I get results, but when I want to see the array I dont get any data in it.

So for example Im using this to save all matching lines into the array

> function pasar_a_word($archivo)  {
>
> ```
> $content = Get-Content $root\UNB\FACTURA_FINAL\$archivo
> $pattern = '(\d\.\d\d) (\D+?) (\d+,\d\d\d\.\d\d)'
>
> Write-Host "FUNCION PASAR A WORD"
>
> for($i = 0; $i -lt $content.Count; $i++){
>  
>    $line = $content[$i]     
>    $results = ([regex]::Matches($line, $pattern)).Value       
>    }
>
>    Write-Host $results[1]  }
> ```

Comment: you need to be precise in details of the pattern to match otherwise is hard to help you. i.e.: does the quantity always have 1 digit followed by a dot followed by 2 digits? does the price always have 2 digits followed by comma followed by 3 digits a dot a 2 digits?

Comment: How do I save the patterns into an array?. So for example if I have the following text

2.00 CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00 1.00 ENSALADA QUINUA 7,309.00

I save in one position 2.00 CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00

And in the second position 1.00 ENSALADA QUINUA 7,309.00

Comment: Too bad it's not a csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the regex static `.Matches()` method for this:

```
$string  = '2.00 CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00 1.00 ENSALADA QUINUA 7,309.00'
$results = ([regex]::Matches($string, '(\d\.\d{2}\s[\w\s]+\d+,[\d.]+)')).Value

# $results[0] --> 2.00 CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00
# $results[1] --> 1.00 ENSALADA QUINUA 7,309.00
```

---

If as it now looks, your file is like

```
2.00 CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00
1.00 ENSALADA QUINUA 7,309.00
3.00 CEBICHE CORVINA PI   26,805.00
```

Then I would recommend using the very fast `switch` for this, parsing the file line-by-line and outputting an array of **objects**

```
# change these paths to suit your environment
$root    = 'X:\Somewhere\UNB\FACTURA_FINAL'
$archivo = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'factura.txt'
# example: keep the same name and path for the output, just change the extension to .csv
$fileOut = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($archivo, '.csv')

$result = switch -Regex -File $archivo {
    '^([\d,.]+)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+([\d,.]+)' { 
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            Quantity = $matches[1]
            Product  = $matches[2].Trim()
            Price    = $matches[3]
        }
    }
}

# display on console
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as structured Csv file so you can open in Excel by double-click
$result | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

If you rather have this as function:

```
function Convert-MyFile {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias ('Archivo')]
        [ValidateScript( { Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf } )]
        [string]$Path
    )

    $result = switch -Regex -File $Path {
        '^([\d,.]+)\s+([\w\s]+)\s+([\d,.]+)' { 
            [PsCustomObject]@{
                Quantity = $matches[1]
                Product  = $matches[2].Trim()
                Price    = $matches[3]
            }
        }
    }
    # output the aray.
    # because arays are 'unrolled' when returning from a function, prefix it with the unary comma
    ,@($result)
}

#usage:
$root    = 'X:\Somewhere\UNB\FACTURA_FINAL'
$archivo = Join-Path -Path $root -ChildPath 'factura.txt'

$result = Convert-MyFile $archivo

# display on console
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# save as structured Csv file so you can open in Excel by double-click
$fileOut = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($archivo, '.csv')
$result | Export-Csv -Path $fileOut -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

In the console screen, the output will be

```
Quantity Product            Price    
-------- -------            -----    
2.00     CAUSA PERUANA GRAN 32,504.00
1.00     ENSALADA QUINUA    7,309.00 
3.00     CEBICHE CORVINA PI 26,805.00
```

Regex details:

```
^                Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\d,.]        Match a single character present in the list below
                 A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
                 A single character from the list “,.”
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)               
\s               Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
   +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   [\w\s]        Match a single character present in the list below
                 A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
                 A “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)               
\s               Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
   +             Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [\d,.]        Match a single character present in the list below
                 A “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
                 A single character from the list “,.”
      +          Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
```

Comment: I edited the main question so you can see in a better formatting

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez AHA,  now I see that the lines are separate, each on a single line. In that case things are much easier. Unfortunately I 'm on mobile now, so it will have to wait until tomorrow before I can help you..

Comment: Thanks Theo! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks Theo ! I made it work for my case with a few tweaks here and there.

Thanks so much for your help !

Comment: Theo ! There is something weird going on... if there is only one match the result object I get its an System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject instead of an array. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez Ok, I have changed the final line in the function from `,$result` into `,@($result)`. The `@()` forces the variable to become an array, even when there is only one element in it. The unary comma still is needed. That will wrap the (now always array) into another single-item array. Upon receiving this output from the function, PowerShell will 'unroll' this outer array, leaving you with the original array in $result.

Comment: Theo. Is there a way that it can accept special character in the text part? Like Ñ

Thanks in advance !

Comment: @JuanManuelSanchez  Save all files with encoding utf8, including the script itself. Add `-Encoding utf8` to the final Export-Csv line. That should do it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
$example_line = '3.00 CEBICHE CORVINA PI   26,805.00'

# Expression Pattern
$pattern = '(\d\.\d\d) (\D+?) (\d+,\d\d\d\.\d\d)'

# Use the -match operator to match the string against the pattern
$match = $example_line -match $pattern

# If the match is successful, extract the three captured groups
if ($match) {
    $quantity = $matches[1]
    $description = $matches[2]
    $price = $matches[3]

    # Print the extracted values
    Write-Output "Quantity: $quantity"
    Write-Output "Description: $description"
    Write-Output "Price: $price"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper pattern is

```
$pattern= '\d.\d\d \D* \d*,\d*.\d*'
```